# If block UI if no internet connection then can Apple Reject App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

If No Internet connection and I block UI with present one View controller with "Please check your Internet Connection" pop up then Can Apple reject my application for blocking UI?

Comment: Nope, Apple will approve your app. I have done that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I don't work at Apple, but I guess if an app requires an internet access to work properly, it is fine to *block* the UI until the user has an actual internet access.
Think about social network apps, if you just installed Facebook app, you would not be able to login upon first launch if you don't have an internet access.

However, blocking the UI seems a little bit strong and probably bad UX as well. Nevertheless, it **should** not prevent you from publishing your app to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Vibha Singh,

Why block the UI ??? Blocking the UI is probably the worst user experience. Apple might not reject it (not sure as I never tried it before but certainly people will not appreciate it)

In case you have an app which you dont want to work when there is no internet then consider designing a screen which you will load which will have text saying "No internet connection try connecting your device to internet something like that"

Facebook, Twitter all the main stream app's follows the same approach rather then blocking UI

Comment: I want to design app like Android Uber and in that they block the ui with showing one gray screen with only one pop up.

Comment: @vibha-singh : Why do you think its a blocked UI ?? it may be a screen with no UI components to interact with :) UI can be considerred as blocked if you have components and you cant tap on it :)

Comment: Think clash of clans. If you don't have internet they will show a pop up with there little splash screen behind it, and then just reloading the launch page until it finds internet. Just because you have a gray screen instead of a fancy splash art in the background doesn't make your use case any different.